# Sort a multidimensional array by values in a column

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [brand] => blah blah
            [location] => blah blah
            [address] => blah blah
            [city] => blah blah
            [state] => CA
            [zip] => 90210
            [country] => USA
            [phone] => 555-1212
            [long] => -111
            [lat] => 34
            [distance] => 3.08
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [brand] => blah blah
            [location] => blah blah
            [address] => blah blah
            [city] => blah blah
            [state] => CA
            [zip] => 90210
            [country] => USA
            [phone] => 555-1212
            [long] => -111
            [lat] => 34
            [distance] => 5
        )
.
.
.

}
```

I want to be able to sort the arrays in the hash by distance.

Comment: array_multisort is backwards: It sorts a column array. (In fact, it sorts multiple independent arrays representing columns.) This is almost never what you want: Either transpose your array, or use something useful like usort.

Answer (score 25):

You need to extract all the distances first, then pass both the distance and the data to the function. As shown in example 3 in the [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) documentation.

```
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $distance[$key] = $row['distance'];
}

array_multisort($distance, SORT_ASC, $data);
```

This assumes you want the shortest distances first, otherwise change the `SORT_ASC` to `SORT_DESC`

Answer (score 16):

If you want to avoid the looping you can use the [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function to achieve your target.
For Example,

You want to sort below array with distance sort

```
$arr = array( 
  0 => array( 'lat' => 34, 'distance' => 332.08 ),
  1 => array( 'lat' => 34, 'distance' => 5 ),
  2 => array( 'lat' => 34, 'distance' => 34 )
);
```

Using below single line your array will be sort by distance

```
array_multisort( array_column( $arr, 'distance' ), SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC, $arr );
```

Now, **$arr** contain with **sorted** array by **distance**

Answer (score 4):

The advantage to calling `usort()` instead of `array_multisort()`, is that you don't need to pre-iterate the input array to generate an array of columnar data.

The following one-liner will use PHP7.4's arrow function syntax with PHP7's "spaceship operator" / "three-way comparison operator" to sort the input array (by reference) based on the distance column values.

With `$a` on the left side of `<=>` and `$b` on the right side, ascending order is used.  To achieve descending sorting, write `$b['distance'] <=> $a['distance']`.

Code:

```
usort($array, fn($a, $b) => $a['distance'] <=> $b['distance']);

var_export($array);
```

---

To break ties while sorting, you can declare multiple values to sort on via arrays of values.

The following will sort by:

1. distance ASC then
2. country DESC then
3. state ASC then
4. city ASC

Code:

```
usort(
    $array,
    fn($a, $b) =>
        [$a['distance'], $b['country'], $a['state'], $a['city']]
        <=>
        [$b['distance'], $a['country'], $b['state'], $b['city']]
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use can use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php);

```
function cmpDistance($a, $b) {
    return ($a['distance'] - $b['distance']);
}

usort($array, "cmpDistance");
```

Comment: The reason many compare functions return positive/negative number instead of explicitly -1 and 1 is to make functions like this simpler. The body of the function can just be `return $a['distance'] - $b['distance']`

Comment: why do I get a "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare cmp()"? Im confused

Comment: @dst11, just rename the function name to some other name, you probably already have it defined somewhere.

Comment: weird, it is ALMOST sorted out... hahaha for some reason, some entries are still unsorted. Could it be related that the distance is of type double? im not understanding this.

Comment: @dst11, Are the "distance" fields always valid numbers? You could try using `return (floatval($a['distance']) - floatval($b['distance']));`.

Comment: yes, before the sorting the distances are: 1.95, 2.31, 4.04, 4.9, 1.58, 404... and some more. Afterwards I get 0.42, 1.24, 2.27, 1.57... etc... what could be wrong here?

Comment: i fixed it by adding (int) in front of the $a['distance'] and $b['distance']. Hope this is the right answer

Comment: @dst11, I don't think this is the correct way because `(int)1.1 == (int)1.9` (casting will only cut of the decimal part), that means entries with such distances would get treated as having the same distance. Use `(float)` or `floatval()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This code helps to sort the multidimensional array using [array_multisort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

```
  $param_dt = array();
  foreach ($data_set as $key => $row) {
     if(isset($row['params']['priority']))
     {
       $param_dt[$key] = $row['params']['priority'];
     }
     else
     {
        $param_dt[$key] = -2; // if priority key is not set for this array - it first out
     }
    }

  array_multisort($param_dt, SORT_ASC,SORT_NUMERIC, $data_set);
```

Now `$data_set` has the sorted list of elements.

Answer (score 1):

We have an array of rows, but array_multisort() requires an array of columns, so we use the below code to obtain the columns, then perform the sorting.

```
// as of PHP 5.5.0 you can use array_column() instead of the above code
$brand= array_column($data, 'brand');
$city= array_column($data, 'city');

// Sort the data with volume descending, edition ascending
// Add $data as the last parameter, to sort by the common key
array_multisort($brand, SORT_DESC, $city, SORT_ASC, $data);
```