# Multidimensional array sort in AS3

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-3, sorting, multidimensional-array

What would be the easiest way to do a multi sort in AS3. Something similar to array_multisort() in PHP... like this: [sort a multidimentional array using array_multisort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305594/sort-a-multidimentional-array-using-array-multisort)

What I have

```
var COUNTRIES:Array = [["AD","Andorra"],["AE","United Arab Emirates"],["AF","Afghanistan"],["AG","Antigua & Barbuda"],["AI","Anguilla"]];
```

.. which looped outputs

```
Andorra
United Arab Emirates
Afghanistan
Antigua & Barbuda
Anguilla
```

... what I need is to sort it against the second index of each, so I get

```
Afghanistan
Andorra
Anguilla
Antigua & Barbuda
United Arab Emirates
```

Comment: Try `COUNTRIES.sortOn('1')`

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008806/as3-sorting-an-array-of-nested-arrays/8010254#8010254 for details.

Comment: Also: try reading the docs ([Array#sortOn()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sortOn%28%29))

Comment: OMG... I'm so lame. Thank you 32bitkid. It worked... ad an answer so I can vote it.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I did that... I've been a Flash dev for 12 years and have never had a momentary slip in thinking like this one. I feel like a total bonehead right now ;) Must be the 14-18 hr work days atm...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simple:

```
 COUNTRIES.sortOn("1");
```

It works because you can access an array index by using a string, just like a property: `array["0"]`. So `sortOn` uses the `"1"` 'property' of each inner array for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to use an Array of Objects

```
  var countries:Array = [{abb:"AD", name:"Andorra"} //etc...];
```

You could then use the Array [sortOn](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sortOn%28%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

You best create an array of Objects instead of an array of arrays, then use [Array.sortOn](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sortOn%28%29):

```
var COUNTRIES : Array = 
    [ { short:"AD",long:"Andorra"}, 
      {short:"AE", long:"United Arab Emirates"}, 
      {short:"AF", long:"Afghanistan"}// and so forth
    ];

COUNTRIES.sortOn ("long"); // sorts by long name
COUNTRIES.sortOn ("short"); // sorts by short name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Array.sort() method.

```
var COUNTRIES:Array = [[AD,Andorra],[AE,United Arab Emirates],[AF,Afghanistan],[AG,Antigua & Barbuda],[AI,Anguilla]];

COUNTRIES = COUNTRIES.sort(sortOnName);

function sortOnName(a:Array, b:Array):Number {
    var aName:String = a[1];
    var bName:String = b[1];

    if(aName > bName) {
        return 1;
    } else if(aName < bName) {
        return -1;
    } else  {
        //aName == bName
        return 0;
    }
}
```