# How to sort multidimensional array in PHP version 5.4?

Tags: php

I have an array structure whose `print_r` output looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Game
            [1] => Date
            [2] => Site
            [3] => Address
            [4] => FirstName
            [5] => LastName
            [6] => Email
            [7] => Phone
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => B-Dry @ Blue Wave DH
            [1] => 7/9/2019 13:00
            [2] => Blue Wave Dover City Park
            [3] => Dover
            [4] => John
            [5] => Doe
            [6] => john.doe@perrylocal.org
            [7] => (555) 555-4797
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => B-Dry @ Blue Wave DH
            [1] => 7/9/2019 13:00
            [2] => Blue Wave Dover City Park
            [3] => Dover
            [4] => Frank
            [5] => Sinatra
            [6] => frank@sinatra.com
            [7] => (555) 685-5555
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => B-Dry @ Gnaden
            [1] => 6/7/2019 18:00
            [2] => Gnaden Indian Valley HS
            [3] => Gnadenhutten
            [4] => Jimmy
            [5] => Dean
            [6] => jimmy@dean.org
            [7] => (330) 555-5555
        )
   [...many more...]
)
```

*The data comes from an excel spreadsheet. If it came from SQL, sorting would be trivial. :-)*

How can I sort/resequence this array as follows:

1. ignore first array set (column labels, not data)
2. sort first by index 0 (ex: "B-Dry @ Blue Wave DH")
3. sort second by index 1 (ex: "7/9/2019 13:00")
4. sort third by index 2 (ex: "Blue Wave Dover City Park")

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305594/sort-a-multidimentional-array-using-array-multisort) seems promising, but I believe that `array_column` works only in PHP 5.5 which I cannot upgrade to yet. And I'm unsure how to exclude the first array set (column labels) in all cases.

Comment: How is this data created? The best way to sort an array into a useful structure is at the source where it's first created - like a database query. If this is not possible then you can loop the array. I'm not sure an out-of-the-box PHP function will do this without some kind of looping

Comment: **(1)** `unset($array[0]);` to get rid of the column names there. **(2)** There is nothing special about `array_column()` aside from convenience; you can easily use `array_map()` or a traditional `foreach(){}` loop and get the same outcome. **(3)** Check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/51385519/2191572 to learn about `array_multisort()` **(4)** Last but not least, if you can sort it properly before PHP gets it then do that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that will sort your multidimensional array by the amount of columns you want:

```
function mult_usort(&$arr, $max_index = false, $index = 0) {

    // Done on purpose, could not use a closure
    function mult_usort_callback($a, $b, $max_index, $index) {
        $max_index = $max_index ?: (count($a) - 1);

        // Recursive to sort till the max index
        if ($a[$index] == $b[$index]) {
            if ($index < $max_index) {
                return mult_usort_callback($a, $b, $max_index, ($index + 1));
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return $a[$index] > $b[$index] ? 1 : -1;
    };

    usort($arr, create_function('$a, $b', 'return mult_usort_callback($a, $b, ' . $max_index . ', ' . $index . ');'));
}
```

And use it like:

```
// Remove the 1st item
array_shift($data);

// Change the date & time column to DateTime objects for proper comparison
// DateTime: PHP >= 5.2
$data = array_map(function ($item) {
    $item[1] = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $item[1]);
    return $item;
}, $data);

// Then sort with the function, till index 2
mult_usort($data, 2);
```

This function uses:

- [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)
- [`create_function()` *deprecated as of PHP 7.2*](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php)

---

If your data is the result of a SQL query, you better `ORDER` inside your query, this will be easier and **faster**.
See also: *[updated function for associative arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51859071/how-to-sort-multidimensional-array-in-php-version-5-4-with-keys/#answer-51860124)*

Comment: AymDev, this looks very promising, but can I infer from your anonymous function that you're sorting only the first two columns? And not including the third column in the sort?

Comment: @HerrimanCoder the function do sorts by the 3rd column, look at the nested `if`s: if the 1st and 2nd columns are equals it sorts by the 3rd (index `2`). I think I could improve this code to make a recursive function with a maximum index parameter, in case you need to sort by many indexes it would prevent writing too many nested conditions and it would be reusable. Tell me if you'd like me to improve this, I could edit my answer tomorrow ;-)

Comment: Note that with PHP7, multidimensional array ordering with `usort` is easier with the spaceship operator. But this is fun to do anyway :-)

Comment: @HerrimanCoder You can check my answer again, I found a way to make a more reusable function.

Comment: AymDev this is brilliant. Thank you for the excellent answer.

Comment: AymDev, could you take a look at my very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51859071/how-to-sort-multidimensional-array-in-php-version-5-4-with-keys

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the first element, simply:

```
unset($array[0]);
```

And then use usort function along with DateTime comparison:

```
    <?php

$data = [
    [
            'Game',
            'Date',
            'Site',
            'Address',
            'FirstName',
            'LastName',
            'Email',
            'Phone'
    ],
    [
            'B-Dry @ Gnaden',
            '6/7/2019 18:00',
            'Gnaden Indian Valley HS',
            'Gnadenhutten',
            'Jimmy',
            'Dean',
            'jimmy@dean.org',
            '(330) 555-5555'
    ],
    [
            'B-Dry @ Blue Wave DH',
            '7/9/2019 19:00',
            'Blue Wave Dover City Park',
            'Dover',
            'John',
            'Doe',
            'john.doe@perrylocal.org',
            '(555) 555-4797'
    ],
    [
            'B-Dry @ Blue Wave DH',
            '7/9/2019 13:00',
            'Blue Wave Dover City Park',
            'Dover',
            'Frank',
            'Sinatra',
            'frank@sinatra.com',
            '(555) 685-5555'
    ]
];

    unset($data[0]);

    usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
       if ($a[0] == $b[0]) {
           $d1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y h:i',$a[1]);
           $d2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y h:i',$b[1]);
           if ($d1 == $d2) {
                if ($a[2] == $b[2]) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return ($a[2] < $b[2]) ? -1 : 1;
           }
           return ($d1 < $d2) ? -1 : 1;
       }
       return ($a[0] < $b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
    });

    var_dump($data, true);
```

Checked at:https://3v4l.org/uMacS

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. There are more parent arrays than just `0`. Also how does it sort by index 0, 1, 2 in order if they're removed?

Comment: 1.  The question says ignore 0th index. Even if there are multiple child arrays like 0th index a simple for loop can take care of that all you need to do is check the value and unset the array index. 2. As we are sorting by using user defined sorting by using usort, it ignores removed indices. 3. You can the the out at the link I have provided at the end of the answer.

Comment: I am updating the answer.

Comment: The issue with earlier link was due to incorrect date format and not comparing the date formatted dates.